# This looks like a simple exponent, but how to solve it?

Tags: exponentiation

Can anyone help with finding the $x$?

$$\frac{998^{999}+998^{998}}{998^{999x}}=999$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: HINT: What’s the greatest common divisor of the summands in the numerator?

Comment: Notice that$$
t^{t-(t+1)x} \left(t+1\right)=\frac{t^{t+1} +t^{t}}{t^{(t+1)x}} = t+1
$$
So if $t \neq -1$, then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{998^{999} + 998^{998}}{998^{999x}} = 999 
\\ \Rightarrow \frac{998^{998}(998 + 1)}{998^{999x}} = \frac{998^{998} \cdot 999}{998^{999x}}= 999
\\ \Rightarrow 998^{998} \cdot 999 = 999 \cdot 998^{999x}
\\ \Rightarrow 998^{998} = 998^{999x} \\ \Rightarrow 998 = 999x \\ \Rightarrow x = \frac{998}{999}
$$